# Rails - Project.where(created_at: (Time.now - 24.hours)..Time.now) returning <Project::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f5470c7a378>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What im trying to do is get a count of all projects posted in the last 24 hours.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_action :projects_today

  def projects_today
    @projects_today = Project.where(created_at: (Time.now - 24.hours)..Time.now)
  end

end
```

**view**

```
<h1><%= @projects_today %></h1>
```

However whats showing up in the view is " Project::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f5470c7a378
" instead of 62 which is the desired answer.

Comment: `.count` and you can remove the question

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean the question? Only using rails 1 week.

Comment: Well, that's ok. But it's a "read the guide"/rtfm question and is unlikely to help anyone. I guess no one expects printing an object to return some arbitrary count.

Comment: Ah sorry i get what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add [`count`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods/count):

```
@projects_today = Project.where(created_at: (Time.now - 24.hours)..Time.now).count
```

Comment: Simple as that. Excellent. It works. Must wait 10 minutes to accept as correct answer.